# My app crashes on Heroku, and I can't understand Heroku logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, redmine-plugins

I develop a Redmine plugin in Ruby on Rails.
Locally, the application works fine both in development and production modes.

But when I deploy it to Heroku, some pages are crashing, specifically some (but not all) custom tabs in project page.
I can't understand the log received by command `heroku logs`. They don't contain errors in my code, only framework modules without error descriptions.

Ruby versions are same at me and Heroku (the only difference is a platform - x86_64-linux at Heroku and i386-mingw32 at me)

May be reason in different DBMS - Heroku uses Postgres and I use Sqlite? But crashing page has no data yet, and I don't commit sqlite gems and settings.

Here are the logs:

```
    > vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-openid-1.4.2/lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/request_store-1.0.5/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-xml_parser-1.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/xml_params_parser.rb:16:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    > vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    > vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    > vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    > vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: paste the full log. In a separate window, run `heroku logs --tail` and only then run the application so you get the full log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was need to run `heroku logs --tail` command for receive full logs.
There I saw my bug, it was in wrong query parameters.

```
MyEntity.where 'id in (?)', my_array
```

`id` field has integer type when `my_array` contains non-integer elements

Thanks [franciscod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5109168/franciscod) for advice about logs!